# Using dynamic runtimeLibrary despite "static" in cpp.runtimeLibrary in qbs profile

Tags: linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking, qbs

I have some qbs project and I've met with some strange behavior of linking with runtime library.

I used Qt static libraries and custom modules

```
//---------MyQtGuiApplication.qbs
import qbs

MyQtApplication {
    Depends { name: "Qt.gui" }
    Depends {
        name: "Qt"
        submodules: Qt.gui.defaultQpaPlugin
        condition: linkDefaultQpaPlugin && Qt.gui.defaultQpaPlugin
    }
    property bool linkDefaultQpaPlugin: Qt.gui.isStaticLibrary
}


//---------MyQtApplication.qbs
import qbs

MyNativeBinary {
    type: ["application"]

    Depends { name: "Qt.core" }
}


//---------MyNativeBinary.qbs
import qbs
import qbs.Environment

NativeBinary {
    Depends { name: "cpp" }
    property bool err: console.error(name + "______" + cpp.runtimeLibrary)
}
```

And simple example

```
//---------test.qbs
import qbs

Project {
    MyQtGuiApplication {

        name: "test"

        Depends { name: "cpp" }
        // cpp.runtimeLibrary: "static"

        files: ["*.h", "*.cpp", "*.ui", "*.qrc", "*.rc"]
    }
}
```

I clearly defined `profiles.windows-x86-msvc14.cpp.runtimeLibrary: "static"`, and it isn't override by inheritance or qbs files. ***But if I dont define it in qbs files, I get***

```
error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary'
```

I'd like to save modularity and not duplicate this parameter.
Have you any idea, why is this happening?

Comment: If you are completely sure that you are really using this profile for building, then I suggest you file a bug report at bugreports.qt.io, with a complete example project. Note that qbs's Qt modules also set this property for a static Qt build, so you shouldn't really have to do anything.

Comment: @ChristianKandeler, I found out, that my application has dependency of Qt.core, that has cheсking `cpp.runtimeLibrary: qbs.toolchain.contains("msvc")
        ? config.contains("static_runtime") ? "static" : "dynamic"
        : original`, but `static_runtime` is a string, that doesnt appear in any qbs's Qt modules. I think, it is not an ideal prioities hierarchy for overriding clue build parametres.

Comment: The value in the profile always takes precedence. Note that AFAIK "static_runtime" is a feature you have to explicitly enable when building Qt. It's not set for every static build.

Comment: You must pass `-static-runtime` to Qt's configure to enable `static_runtime`.

You cannot mix the runtimes. Qt's runtime must be the same as the one your project uses.

Comment: @hole-otter-rosy, exactly as it is - everywhere is static. I dont understand, why does this build steps try to use dynamic link.

Comment: @ChristianKandeler, I found [this commit](https://github.com/qbs/qbs/commit/130897199664f52d737ad4f3e24df19ccfbdee93), and I suggested, that creating new profiles with prereleased 1.13 version of qbs could resolve problem (despit 1.12 that I used before). But in my new Qt profile i have the same checking in `Qt.core` file

Comment: No, there were no functional changes. I suggest you create a bug report at bugreports.qt.io, with an example project attached.

Comment: @KkVova "everywhere is static"... That is not the case.
There are more players involved:
 - your application (static)
 - Qt  (static)
 - the MSVC runtime your application uses (static)
 - the MSVC runtime Qt uses (*dynamic*)

The latter two must match.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QBS-1431